# Laravel Nova - Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough::save()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have three models

```
Subject
  id
  name

Post
  id
  name
  subject_id

Comment
  id
  name
  post_id
```

Relationships look so:

```
Subject hasMany Post
Post belongsTo Subject

Post hasMany Comment
Comment belongsTo Post

Subject hasManyThrough Comment
```

everything is displayed correctly in Nova on the Subject page
[image]

but the problem is when I click **Create Comment** from the subject page and click on **save** an error occurs: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough::save()

[image]

I know hasManyThrough relationship causes the issue as it does not have a direct relation to Subject but I can't figure out how to solve this as I am new to Nova and don't know much about customization.

[image: nova resource for Subject]

here is nova resource for Subject